# facebook comments, what happens when domainname change?

Tags: facebook, dns, facebook-comments

I am currently developing a new blog platform  with some new features. For the commenting on blog posts i'll use facebook comment. (each user has to create their own account for comments on facebook).

But i have one problem.

Each user can, whenever they want change their account name (subdomain name), and also the domain they use. ( i have several domains available).

But when facebook comments use the href of each page to sort the comments i am afraid there will be a lot of lost comments for my users. when they change account name..

What happens with the comments when I change the domain / subdomain but keep the folder structure & filename as before? is there a way to convert the old "href" values to the new with the new domain name?

How to solve this? any ideas?

As i understand, the XID value is the old way of sorting comments, and you should use href?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this a custom Facebook app or are you using their default commenting system?  If you created a custom app, the comments may be associated with your XID.

However, if you are using the default commenting you might have problems.  Facebook comments rely completely on the URL that they are associated with.  So, you will lose comments when moving to a new domain.

With that said, you might be able to reference the old URL from your new domain name and pull the old comments.

Comment: I guess that i mean their default commenting, but... I didn't know that there where 2 different commenting systems?! i think i have to go and read more. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I remember Facebook Connect used to have the ability to store comments and associate them with the App's XID, as opposed to the URL.  But Facebook's new commenting system only stores the comments with the URL.  I apologize if I wasn't clear in my initial post, but hopefully I can help point you in the right direction.